# How can I set smaller line space in a caption in tikzposter?

Tags: line-spacing, tikzposter

I am using tikzposter and I have a `tikzfigure` with a caption, in a `subcol`. I find the line spacing for the caption ridiculously big. Is there any chance I can make it smaller ?

[image: illustration of problem]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most made mistakes done in a class file, not ending the group with a paragraph so LaTeX can apply the correct line spacing. This will hopefully be fixed in upcoming versions of `tikzposter`.

[image: tiksposterLinespaceCaption]

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{columns}
    \column{.32}
\block{Walzing Wombat}{%
    \begin{tikzfigure}[\normalsize this is to test the
        spacing within the caption and we need quite a
    lot of words here just to see some minimal result,
exhausting]
        \rule{5cm}{2cm}
    \end{tikzfigure}
    Wombats love the walz, ducks dance dixie
}
\column{.32}
\block{lurking lizard}{%
    \begin{tikzfigure}[\normalsize this is to test the
        spacing within the caption and we need quite a
    lot of words here just to see some minimal result,
exhausting\par]
        \rule{5cm}{2cm}
    \end{tikzfigure}
    sassy salamandar
}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: They haven't fix it yet.